# Connect fandjango (Facebook django) user to Django User to add attributes

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-canvas, fandjango

I'm new to FanDjango, and trying to understand something. I've got everything set up and working beautifully, and I can pole request.facebook.user and get info.

But now, I want to develop an application that has more info than just Facebook gives me about each user. For example, I want to store up/down votes this user has mode on other objects (i.e. relations). I want to store user settings. Etc... The standard "Django Way" is to use a User Profile, but I don't know how to connect FanDjango's user to the user profile.

I'm unclear how to do this.

I looked into django-facebook before fandjango, and I couldn't get it to work which is why I moved to this. What they do is, they allow your user-profile to inherit from their user definition. Can the same kind of thing work here, or should I be doing something different?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can simply create a `Profile` model and give it a [`OneToOneField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-one-relationships) pointing to the Fandjango profile

```
class Profile(models.Model):
     facebook_user = models.OneToOneField("fandjango.User")
     votes = ...
```

which will allow you to get the Fandjango profile given the Profile and visa versa:

```
request.facebook.user.profile
```

and in reverse:

```
profile.facebook_user
```

An issue with this is that because you aren't using `django.contrib.auth` at all, you don't get any of it's nice features such as being able to use `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` etc.

EDITED TO ADD:

Extra details provided here: https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango/issues/63#issuecomment-4988917

> Then I just listen for the post_save signal of "Fandjango.models.User"
>   and when the "created" parameter is set, I instantiate the Profile
>   model.
>
> ```
> @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
> def profile_creation(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
>     if created:
>         profile, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
> ```

Comment: Yes, that's probably the approach I will take. Is it really a problem losing the django.contrib.auth, if I'm a Facebook app and will only have Facebook users?

Comment: This is what some user on the project's GitHub answered to the same question, and was confirmed by FanDjango's author as the right approach. See: https://github.com/jgorset/fandjango/issues/63#issuecomment-4988917